# Getting a list of terms by distance/occurance to another term in Solr

Tags: solr, solr4

Is there a way in Solr to get a list of Terms by their distance to another term, similar to the TermsComponent which can return terms by their count in a document?

For instance, if I have the following text indexed:

> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.

and

> What does the fox say?

And I searched for the term 'fox', I would expect the following output:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">7</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="terms">
        <lst name="text">
            <int name="brown">0</int>
            <int name="jumped">0</int>
            <int name="say">0</int>
            <int name="the">1</int>
            <int name="quick">1</int>
            <int name="over">1</int>
            <int name="does">1</int>
            <int name="what">2</int>
            <int name="lazy">3</int>
            <int name="dogs">4</int>
        </lst>
    </lst>
</response>
```

In this example I am using a VERY simple algorithm to calculate the value ( total_word_distance / number_of_docs_appeared).  For example, 'The' occurs in both documents, once with a distance of 0 and another with a distance of 2, so `(0 + 2) / 2` give the answer of 1.

Again, what I am asking is if something like this already exists, and if not, how would one go about do this?